# State value being changed even if action/reducer doesn't change that value

Tags: reactjs, redux, reference, state, action

I am using the same action payload to set two different values on the state with the same content.

This is so that I can have the original data before it has any changes and can compare them in the end, something like:

```
onLoadUserDataSuccess

userData: action.payload
originalUserData: action.payload
```

The problem is that when I have an action that updates the user data but only changes the userData value and not the originalUserData, I can see in the devtools that both change. Example:

```
onUserDataUpdate

userData: action.payload
```

The only reason I can imagine is that somehow this is being handled by reference? So automatically the originalUserData will change when the userData value changes?

I've also tried having this original data saved inside the component state with the WillMount hook, but this doesnt work well if I load other users in the meantime since the component wont remount, so the data is from the first user loaded.

Comment: the comparison logic for `userData` and `originalUserData` can be achieved by  React's `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`

Answer (score 0):

After quite a lot of reading, as expected, the issue is with the fact that arrays and objects are handled by reference and using react with redux requires extra care when handling action payloads.

The solution is to create a function that will return a new state on each nested level.

This can be done also by other libraries like Immutable.js and immer.

More on Immutable Update Patterns [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)